# Counting with reduce() - where the values come from?

Tags: javascript, reduce

While learning to filter out values which appear only once in array, I came across a very useful piece of code which I adjusted for my needs. I started to analyze how the counting of repetition of one value is performed. Below I have a function which does the counting.

```
function countInstancesOfAppearance(word) {
    var letters = word.split('');

    return countLetters = letters.reduce(function(object, key) {
      object[key] = object[key] ? object[key] + 1 : 1;
      return object;
    }, {});
}
```

And the result is: `{l: 1, a: 1, s: 2, o: 1}`.

However, I cannot understand what is going on behind the `object[key] + 1 : 1`. For me much more clearer would be to have the function written in a following way:

```
function countInstancesOfAppearance(word) {
    var letters = word.split('');

    return countLetters = letters.reduce(function(object, key) {
      if (object[key] = object[key]) {
        object[key] = object[key] + 1; 
      } else {
        object[key] = 1;
      }

      return object;
    }, {});
}
```

To describe my reasoning better:

```
var obj = {};
obj.cat = ""; // obj = {cat: ""};
obj.cat + 1 // in console, it gives 1, but the object continues to be obj = {cat: ""};
obj.cat = 1 // only now we have obj = {cat: 1};
obj.cat + 1 // the object continues to be obj = {cat: 1};
obj.cat = obj.cat + 1 //only now we have obj = {cat: 2};
```

So can you please explain to me how it happens that reduce() method takes advantage of `obj.cat + 1` or just `1` in the following conditional `object[key] = object[key] ? object[key] + 1 : 1;` to make the proper assignments?

Here is the code with console.logs:

```
function countInstancesOfAppearance(word) {
    var letters = word.split('');

    return countLetters = letters.reduce(function(object, key) {
    console.log("object", object);
    console.log("key", key);
    console.log("object[key] = object[key]", object[key] = object[key]);
      object[key] = object[key] ? object[key] + 1 : 1;
      return object;
    }, {});
}
```

And the output of it:

[image]

Comment: You could just read its documentation to understand how it actually works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Did you mean `if (object[key]) {` instead of `if (object[key] = object[key]) {`?

Comment: `object[key] = object[key]` is not a condition but assignment.

Comment: @Striped you are right, so why is it used in ternary operator? and it works

Comment: @thefourtheye you are right, if (object[key]) works as well

Comment: @Striped, I need to look closer at the console.log.

Comment: @bakrall You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the assignment operator, so

```
object[key] = object[key] ? object[key] + 1 : 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
object[key] = (object[key] ? object[key] + 1 : 1);
```

`object[key]` is set to `1` if it was `undefined` or `0` (as those values are falsy), and incremented in most other cases.

Comment: Thanks to you as well! I did not know that about precedence!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [ternary operator documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
object[key] = object[key] ? object[key] + 1 : 1;
```

can be rewritten

```
if (object[key]) {                  // object[key] alreay exists
    object[key] = object[key] + 1;  // increment its value
} else {
    object[key] = 1;                // object[key] does not exist, initialize it with 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand the logic behind!